# Make Disable date when lower then date start in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

i want i to make my date in my `date_end` is disable if lower the my `date_start`. so the date_end only can input more then the date start

this my javascript :

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var date_input=$('input[name="date_end"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
    var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    date_input.datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      container: container,
      todayHighlight: true,
      autoclose: true,
    })
  })
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var date_input=$('input[name="date_start"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
    var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    date_input.datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
      container: container,
      todayHighlight: true,
      autoclose: true,
    })
  })
</script>
```

and this my form :

```html
<input class="form-control tanggal" id="date" name="date_start"  placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" type="text" required />
<input class="form-control tanggal" id="date_end" name="date_end" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" type="text"/>
```

i ve been try like this :
[image: make]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control tanggal" id="dt1" name="date_start"  placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" type="text" required />
<input class="form-control tanggal" id="dt2" name="date_end" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" type="text"/>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dt1").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            var date2 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
            $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', date2);
            //sets minDate to dt1 date + 1
            $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
        }
    });
    $('#dt2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        onClose: function () {
            var dt1 = $('#dt1').datepicker('getDate');
            console.log(dt1);
            var dt2 = $('#dt2').datepicker('getDate');
            if (dt2 <= dt1) {
                var minDate = $('#dt2').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                $('#dt2').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i try use it but i still can select lower date

Comment: Did you change the `id' of both input fields ?

Comment: sure i try it, but its still wont work for me, or did that have other javascript need to include ?

Comment: You've added two `jQuery` files. Remove one. Add the js file for datepicker above your js code.